# Parsing Midnight as Midnight without Losing a Day in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

C# dates will be the end of me.

In a WebAPI, I need to parse some dates sent from a device in the following format: 
**1944-12-12T00:00:00.000+10:30**

My goal is to parse it so that I have the correct date i.e. 12/12/1944. It keeps flicking it back to 11/12/1944. So, obviously subtracting the offset. But I don't get why. Midnight on 12 Dec 1944 is a point in time. Why can't it just be parsed so you end up with a Datetime that reflects that.

Anyhow, here's some code which I attempted to use:

```
class Program
{
    private static string AppFormatForParsing = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz"; // e.g. "2018-03-29T09:52:46.544+10:30"

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string aDate = "1944-12-12T00:00:00.000+11:00";

        DateTime? d = TryParseExactDateTime(aDate)?.ToLocalTime();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static DateTime? TryParseExactDateTime(string source)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(source, AppFormatForParsing, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var parsedDate))
        {
            return new DateTime(parsedDate.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

That, at least, gets me the right day. But an examination of the DateTime shows a value in the hour property of 9. But it is midnight!

If anyone knows how I can just parse midnight as midnight, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I tihnk this has to do with timezones. Midnight on 12/12 in a +10:30 timezone is still 1:30 pm on 11/12 UTC (i.e. +10:30 timezone is 10h30m ahead of UTC) Edit: Your local time zone will impact this.

Comment: @AndrewP Thanks. I need to find a way to overcome these issues. If only parsing strings to dates was as easy as strings to ints.

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Chances are that instead of casting it to your local time (`ToLocalTime()`), you want to specify a different timezone for everything to work in. Are you just trying to get a DateTime where Date is 12/12 and time is 00:00 ?

Comment: @AndrewP Yes. That's correct. And it becomes challenging when the Timezone of the sending device is different to that of the server.

Comment: Can you just strip the timezone from the string and parse it that way? `AppFormatForParsing = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff"`, `aDate = aDate.Split('+')[0]`  Edit: may need to get a bit smarter when there is a negative time offset

Comment: Datetime will attempt to localize your time into the current servers timezone when parsed with an offset. Use DateTimeOffset instead. If that doesn't work then perhaps you need to use something like Noda Time. But if this the only place you need to do such a thing then you could manipulate the string. I guess it depends on what the time in the response means to you... As pointed out that date is correct when converted to Utc but if you're interested in the time at that offset then of course you'll need to do *something* to "normalize" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fixated on midnight but `aDate` does not refer to an instant in time that is midnight UTC.  Your human eyes read the first part of the string and see "1944-12-12", which is only part of the string.  This leads you to mistakenly think the day in question is December 12, 1944 UTC.  But the **actual instant in time** being referenced is 1:00 PM on December 11, 1944 UTC.  Something has to give here: either you accept the parsing is correct and the correct day is Dec 11, or you transform the input string to refer to a different instant in time.

Since all devices are sending a round-trip formatted string (see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), you can ease the strictness of input format, and use `TryParse`.  This would allow strings such as:

- 1944-12-12T00:00:00.000+11:00
- 1944-12-11T13:00:00.000Z
- 1944-12-11T00:00:00Z
- 1944-12-11Z

By the way, the first 2 strings:

- 1944-12-**12**T00:00:00.000+11:00
- 1944-12-**11**T13:00:00.000Z

**Refer to the exact same instant in time**.  When the string is written with Z, you clearly see the day in question is Dec 11.  The difference between the 2 when parsing is that the first string parses with a DateTimeKind of Local, and the second string with Kind of Utc.

How you return the DateTime is a bit awkward.  It would be simpler just to return `parsedDate.ToUniversalTime()`.  This avoids any Local issues of people running the code in different time zones and seeing different times because they are looking at Local times instead of Utc.

Once you have a DateTime object and you only wish to see the day in question, i.e. focus in on midnight of that day, you would use the `DateTime.Date` property.

If you absolutely insist on transforming the input time string to end at the incorrect midnight, you can use a simple method such as:

```
private static string MutateToMidnight(string source)
{
    var pieces = source.Split(new char[] { 'T' });
    if (pieces.Length == 0 && pieces[0].EndsWith("Z", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return pieces[0];
    }
    return pieces[0] + "Z";
}
```

As mentioned earlier, you can use a TryParse to accommodate variations to the round trip format.  Here is one impementation:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseDateTime(string source)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParse(source, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out var parsedDate))
    {
        return parsedDate.ToUniversalTime(); // .Date;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, I think mutating the original time string is improper.  You would be referring to an instant in time that is different from what was sent.

Comment: I'm going to award this answer, but I have to say that no-one has really helped too much. That is, I've learnt nothing new. Users couldn't give a monkeys about exact points in time and offsets and UTC - these are all developer concepts. Users only requirement is that when they say their birthday is 12 Dec 1944, then the app repeats this every time they log in. They don't want to see 11 Dec 1944, because technically, that was the actual moment of their birth UTC. That's just going to confuse a 76 year old man. This is the dev complexity which I've been grappling with and eventually solved (??).

Comment: .net framework was written for developers, not users. Many developers have the need to track dates across time-zones since we live in a world of connected systems. If you don't need all that there are ways to dumb it down to a simple DOB. Your question has been answered and you have been presented with several options.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a DateTimeOffset to parse correctly

```
    public static DateTimeOffset? TryParseExactDateTime(string source)
    {
        DateTimeOffset parsedDate;

        if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(source, AppFormatForParsing, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
            return new DateTimeOffset(parsedDate.DateTime);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: DateTimeOffset is a struct which IMHO over-promises and under-delivers. I get my desired outcome if the offsets are the same. But if the offset on the server is +10 and the offset on the string is +11, the localtime is the day before (11pm). Still haven't found a silver bullet for these differing offsets. AndrewP's suggestion has come closest, if I can assume there will not be a "-" offset.

Comment: Well in this case it works, regardless of the offset...and you can easily get a DateTime from the result.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing below code, it means **midnight of 1944-12-12 in UTC** + **11:00 ahead**

string aDate = "1944-12-12T00:00:00.000+11:00";

Instead remove the time zone from format and targeted parsing string

```
class Program
{
    private static string AppFormatForParsing = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff"; // e.g. "2018-03-29T09:52:46.544+10:30"

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string aDate = "1944-12-12T00:00:00.000";

        DateTime? d = TryParseExactDateTime(aDate)?.ToLocalTime();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static DateTime? TryParseExactDateTime(string source)
    {
            DateTime parsedDate;

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(source, AppFormatForParsing, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
            {
                return parsedDate;
            }

            return null;
    }
}
```

If later you want to add the difference then you can add it or change the timezone